# Getting Heroku CI test ouput via email

Tags: heroku, heroku-ci

Is there a way to get notified of the test results output for the tests running on a Heroku pipeline. Currently, I can see the results under the "Tests" tab of the pipeline. But is there a way to get a notification when tests fail?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm testing the CI right now, an without notifications makes little sense...

Comment: no. I checked with heroku and they do not have this. Advised to use APIs to poll for this information. I haven't gotten around to it yet.

Comment: The best I got so far is to get the result (success/failure) to a slack Channel. I guess it's ok for now, but this doesn't scale... oh I miss Jenkins :)

Comment: How did you manage that?

Comment: Click on the slack button in heroku's own documentation: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/chatops